# How can I move the footer to the bottom part of the mobile view's first fold?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a page where I've placed content with a footer at the bottom. However, on mobile devices, there's a scrollbar that requires scrolling just to see the footer. What I want is to display the footer within the first fold of the screen.

I attached a sample video recording from the actual mobile render.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/24756141?key=ce7e0984ac89984d2cbf5757cfad06b7

Here's a bit of my snippet:

Body:

```
body {
    color: var(--font-color-primary);
    font-family: 'VAG Rounded Next', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Main content CSS:

```
.jfc {
    border-left: 0.1px solid #929292;
    border-right: 0.1px solid #929292;
    max-width: 430px;
    padding: 32px 38px;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Footer:

```
footer {
    border-top: 0.1px solid #929292;
    border-left: 0.1px solid #929292;
    border-right: 0.1px solid #929292;
    max-width: 430px;
    line-height: 13.78px !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Just curiois, why are you doing borders with 0.1px width?

Comment: @StephenMIrving , to add a border on the side (I'll revise it later, it's from the work of one of our team). In the desktop view, I am restricting my page to render at 480px width.

Comment: Ok, I think your issue could be solved by using the newer dynamic viewport units to set the height on the body. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all the HTML, I think your issue is that you are setting the body height to 100vh, but on mobile devices this 100vh value does not take into account the various bars like tab bars or URL bars that may fade away when a user scrolls down. To correct this, there are new CSS units that take these things into account. The `svh` unit, which is the smallest view height taking into account any URL or tab bars on mobile, `lvh` which is the largest view height, not taking those bars into account (pretty much the same as the old `vh`), and `dvh` which is dynamic view height, which will take them into account when they are there and then shift when they disappear. You should use them with a fallback height with the old `vh` unit for devices that aren't supported yet (though they have [pretty good support now](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_viewport_percentage_units_dynamic), with ~96% device support on mobile).

[image: You can see the difference between svh and lvh illustrated in the following image]

To change your code, try this:

```css
body {
    color: var(--font-color-primary);
    font-family: 'VAG Rounded Next', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100dvh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

If `dvh` doesn't give you the behavior you want, try `svh`. Here is an informative [article on these newer viewport units](https://www.bram.us/2021/07/08/the-large-small-and-dynamic-viewports/) for more information. Basically though, if you are setting height of an element with `vh` units and you want it to look the best on mobile, you should always use one of the newer units, either `svh`, `lvh`, or `dvh` too and use the `vh` height as a fallback for them.

However, if you don't ever want there to be a scrollbar on the page at all, and for the bottom of the footer to always be at the bottom of the screen and never trigger a scrollbar, you should probably also use `overflow: hidden` on the `body`, as this will prevent any scrollbars from appearing (but any content that overflows the screen will not be viewable so ensure that the page is responsive enough for that to be OK) and instead of setting `min-height`, set `height` and `max-height` instead, like this:

```css
body {
    color: var(--font-color-primary);
    font-family: 'VAG Rounded Next', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    height: 100dvh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100dvh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

That way the page will never exceed the size of the viewport. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I still didn't know that CSS has dynamic height.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I already read the article and watched some videos regarding this and it is awesome!. It will help me a lot when it comes in creating responsive heights.